# TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got ['database']; ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django

I'm having a problem adding a set of objects on a *ManyToMany* field on my `Question` model, `Question.tags`. When passing the set of `Tag` instances on the line that contains `question.tags.add(tags)` the following error is raised:

- `TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got ['database']`

Why is adding the list of model instances to the *ManyToMany* field causing this error?

```
class AskQuestionPage(Page):

    template_name = "posts/ask.html"
    extra_context = {
        'title': "Ask a public question"
    }

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = QuestionForm
        return context


    def post(self, request):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        form = context['form'](request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            form.cleaned_data['profile'] = profile
            tags = form.cleaned_data.pop("tags")
            question_tags = []
            for name in tags:
                try:
                    tag = Tag.objects.get(name=name)
                except Tag.DoesNotExist:
                    tag = Tag.objects.create(name=name)
                finally:
                    question_tags.append(tag)
            question = form.save()
            question.tags.add(question_tags)
            return SeeOtherHTTPRedirect(
                reverse("posts:question", kwargs={"id": question.id})
            )
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

```
class QuestionForm(ModelForm):

    title = CharField(
        min_length=20, max_length=80,
        widget=TextInput({"class": "question_input_shade fill_block_width"}),
        error_messages={"max_length": "The title of your question is too long"},
        help_text="Concisely describe the issue"
    )

    body = CharField(
        widget=Textarea(attrs={"class": "question_input_shade fill_block_width adjust_box"}),
        min_length=50,
        help_text="Clarify your question with as much detail as possible",
        error_messages={
            'required': "Elaborate on your question",
            'min_length': "Add more info to your question"
        }
    )

    tags = TagField(
        widget=MultiTagWidget(
            attrs={
                "min_length": 1, "max_length": 25,
                "class": "question_input_shade inline_tag_input"
            }
        ), require_all_fields=False,
        help_text="Add up to 4 tags for your question"
    )
```

```
class Question(Post):

    title = CharField(
        max_length=80, unique_for_date="date",
        help_text="Concisely state the problem you're having",
        error_messages={
            "max_length": "The title of your question is too long"
        }
    )
    tags = ManyToManyField(
        'Tag', related_name="questions", related_query_name="question"
    )
    views = IntegerField(default=0)
    objects = Manager()
    postings = QuestionSearchManager()


    class Meta(Post.Meta):
        db_table = "question"
        ordering = ["-score" , "-date"]
        constraints = [UniqueConstraint(fields=[
            'title', 'date', 'profile'
        ], name="duplicated_post_by_date")]

class Tag(Model):

    name = CharField(unique=True, max_length=25)


    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = "tag"


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
```

Comment: have you tried `question.tags.add(*question_tags)` as it has multiple objects?

Comment: That resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need unpack the values as it has multiple id's associated with it.

```
question.tags.add(*question_tags)
```